# Comment is not adding after click on submit button

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Comment is not adding after clicking it on Add comment,

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post_by = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    body = models.TextField()

    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

Please help me in this. I will really appreciate your Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the action where the form has to submit to, so:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'name-of-detail-view' id=post.pk %}" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
    {{ comment_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

where *`'name-of-the-detail-view'`* should be the name of the view where you handle the comment.

Your view also has some anti-patterns. You can improve this with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def detail_view(request, id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id)
    comments = data.comments.filter(active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.post_by = data
            comment_form.instance.commented_by = request.user
            # shouldn't the comment be active by default?
            comment_form.instance.active = True  # ??
            new_comment = comment_form.save()
            return redirect(detail_view, pk=pk)
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    context = {'data':data,'comments':comments,'comment_form':comment_form}   
    return render(request, 'mains/show_more.html', context )
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225716/discussion-on-answer-by-willem-van-onsem-comment-is-not-adding-after-click-on-su).

Answer (score 1):

couldn't see a problem with templates or else, try this little modification in the views.py ,hope it could help

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

@login_required
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'mains/show_more.html', {'post': post, 
                  'comments':comments, 'new_comment': new_comment,      
                  'comment_form': comment_form})
```